# Dynamically assign image to textbox template in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I had implemented a template for textbox to show image inside it, but the problem I facing is that I unable to show image dynamically. Here is my code

Window.xaml

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource imageTextBox}" />
```

Here is my textbox template

```
<Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="imageTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,8"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                <Border x:Name="bg" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Gray">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource BasicTextBox}" Grid.Column="1" 
                                 Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                 FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                 FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                 FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                 MinWidth="340" Margin="1" />
                        <Image Source="Images/img_1.gif" Width="20"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="BasicTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: What do you mean with *unable to show image dynamically*?

Comment: In style I had assign Image element with static path so whenever I assign the key to text box in windows.xaml it will show me that single image in all text boxes..so for different textbox I require to show different images. How Can I implement it.?

Comment: Add a property for custom control and bind it to image source.

Comment: Either do what IDisposable said, or use the `Tag`-Property. `<Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Width="20"/>`. Then bind your ImageSource to the `Tag`

Comment: I am new to WPF application can you please provide me some detials on how to use Tag-Property

Comment: The answer posted by codekaizen looks bit confusing. Please follow the method suggested by lokusking or use a dependency property and template binding as I suggested.

Comment: Using a `{Binding}` and a view model is far from confusing. You may want to read up on Model-View-ViewModel as a way to use WPF. Using Tag is a poor substitute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `{Binding}` for the `<Image.Source>` property. Here's an [example as a LinqPad query](http://share.linqpad.net/mcl7l5.linq) ([get LinqPad free](http://www.linqpad.net/)):

```
void Main()
{
    // Need to parse XAML since LinqPad doesn't have an integrated XAML build
    var xaml = @"
    <Grid xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
    <Grid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType=""Control"" x:Key=""imageTextBox"">
        <Setter Property=""Margin"" Value=""0,0,0,8""/>
        <Setter Property=""Template"">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType=""Control"">
                    <Border x:Name=""bg"" BorderThickness=""1"" CornerRadius=""3"" BorderBrush=""Gray"">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=""30""/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width=""*""/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Style=""{DynamicResource BasicTextBox}"" Grid.Column=""1""
                                     Foreground=""{TemplateBinding Foreground}""
                                     Background=""{TemplateBinding Background}""
                                     FontFamily=""{TemplateBinding FontFamily}""
                                     FontSize=""{TemplateBinding FontSize}""
                                     FontWeight=""{TemplateBinding FontWeight}""
                                     MinWidth=""340"" Margin=""1"" />
                            <Image Source=""{Binding Image}"" Width=""20""/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property=""IsMouseOver"" Value=""True"">
                            <Setter Property=""BorderBrush"" TargetName=""bg"" Value=""Black""/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property=""IsFocused"" Value=""True"">
                            <Setter Property=""BorderBrush"" TargetName=""bg"" Value=""Black""/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBox Style=""{StaticResource imageTextBox}"" />
    </Grid>
    ";

    // Get some images... these could be in your resources
    var png = PngBitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/Esperanto_star.png"), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
    var vm = new ViewModel { Image = png.Frames[0] };
    var o = (FrameworkElement)XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
    // Set the image source - in this case, a view model
    o.DataContext = vm;
    // Let LinqPad display it
    PanelManager.DisplayWpfElement(o);

    // This code is for the example only, to change the image after 2 seconds.
    var dispatcher = o.Dispatcher;
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        await dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            png = PngBitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Lol_question_mark.png"), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            vm.Image = png.Frames[0];
        }));
    });
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ImageSource _image;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get
        {
            return _image;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_image == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _image = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Image)));
        }
    }
}
```

This example uses a simple view model as the `Binding` source, but it could be any source. There is also code which changes the `Image` value after a 2 second delay to show you that it does in fact update. In your code, you'd omit this and use the way you want to update it.

At first it appears:
[image: First appearance of image]

Then after update:
[image: After update appearance]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Its really helpful.